# Min of two numeric types (including nullable)

Tags: c#, generics

I want a method that returns the smallest of two values, when one value is null it should return the non-null value, and when both are null it should return null.

I created a helper class with the following method `public static T? Min<T>(T? a, T? b)`

I tried to make this very flexible (also support strings etc) by adding the constraints `where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>`, but these won't allow me to pass `int` arguments.

I then tried `where T : INumber<T>`. This worked with `int` arguments, but not with `Nullable<int>` because that type doesn't satisfy the constraint `INumber<Nullable<int>>`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Update: Can't use `where T : struct, IMinMax<T>` due to a bug in Blazor... https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7935

Comment: `public static T? Min<T>(T? a, T? b) where T : struct, INumber<T>`?

Comment: Are those _the same_ numeric types? Or may it be used on for example an `int` and a `double?` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want `T?` to mean `Nullable<T>`, you need to add the `struct` constraint:

```
public static T? Min<T>(T? a, T? b) where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T> 
{ 
    // do your magic here
}
```

Calling it both with int and int? parameters compiles successfully ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DaDQr5)):

```
    int a = 2;
    int? b = 2;
    
    int? c = Min<int>(a, a);
    int? d = Min(a, b);
    int? e = Min(b, b);
```

Apparently, type inference does not work well if both parameters are `int` (maybe because there are other suitable implicit conversions available than those to `int?`?). If that bothers you, you can add a non-nullable `T Min<T>(T a, T b)` overload that handles this special case.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Here is the final version if you'd like to update your calling code sample - https://pastebin.com/g3ZSpCwV

Comment: @PeterMorris: Thanks! Looking at your code, I see that `Min(null, 2)` returns `2`, but `Max(null, 2)` returns `null`. Is that really what you intended? It's OK if you see `null` as "the largest possible number", but it's not OK if you see `null` as "ignore that value, if possible". I assume that you actually wanted the latter.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, generics does not work very well with Nullable. I have not found any way to treat a reference type and a Nullable struct the same way, but I'm not up to date with the latest .Net version.

Your code should work for most numeric types if you specify a struct-constraint

```
public static T? Min<T>(T? a, T? b) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
```

You could then declare a separate method restricted to classes

```
public static T Min<T>(T a, T b) where T : class, IComparable<T>
```

But there might be situations where the overload resolution has issue picking the correct overload. An alternative would be to declare your own `Maybe<T>`/`Option<T>`-type, possibly with an implicit conversion from T. That should allow you to use the same generic method for value and reference types.